# Assembly , moving through an array

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have an array where I have to add all two digit numbers, the part with the 2 digit number sorting works , but I can't seem to take the next digit from my array it always takes the first one

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword


.data 

skaic DWORD 15,20,12,11,15151515
suma DWORD ?
.code

main proc
mov ecx, 0

l1:
    mov ebx,skaic
    add ebx,ecx

    cmp ebx,15151515
    je endl1

    add ecx, 4
    mov eax,ebx
    cmp eax,9
    jng l1

    add suma, eax
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0
    jmp l1

endl1:


    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iv2I.png)

Comment: You did not even load a single item from the array. You are missing `mov ebx, [ebx]`. Could of course be rewritten more efficiently. PS: this looks more like masm than nasm.

Comment: Have you looked at this in the debugger?  What value are you seeing in `ebx`, say at the `cmp .. 1515`?

Comment: It just says exception unhandled If I use the [] brackets.

Comment: Since this is masm, you also need to change `mov ebx,skaic` into `mov ebx, offset skaic`. I correct myself, you did indeed load the first element of the array, but you want to load the address there.

Comment: It shows a value of 15 when I come to cmp 1515

Comment: uhm when I use offset , it tends to set a random value to ebx , atm its set to 4210668

Comment: That is the address of the array. You also need the `mov ebx, [ebx]` after `add ebx,ecx`.

Comment: thank youuuuu it finally works now I'll try to do a few more to actually find out how everything works thoroughly

Comment: Those 3 lines could be simplified to `mov ebx, [skaic+ecx]`

Comment: so offset is sending the address of the array, is it possible to somehow , take the last digit of array? because I want to compare the eax to last digit of array and je endloop1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is MASM code, the `mov ebx, skaic` instruction is retrieving the first element of the array. However seeing the addition with the ECX register and how you raise ECX by 4 throughout the loop, clearly indicates that you expect EBX to contain an address at the same time. It can't be both at once!
The good solution is to maintain a simple pointer that starts by pointing at the first element of the array, and that is incremented by 4 on each iteration of the loop.

```
    mov  ebx, OFFSET skaic  ; Pointing at the first element
T1:
    mov  eax, [ebx]         ; Retrieving the current element
    add  ebx, 4             ; Preparing for the next element
    cmp  eax, 15151515      ; Is it the array terminator
    je   endT1              ; Yes
    cmp  eax, 10
    jb   T1                 ; Has fewer than 2 digits, so don't add
    add  suma, eax
    jmp  T1
endT1:
```

Tip1: Don't use label names like `l1`. These are hard to read! The mention `T1` is already a better choice amongst the non-descriptive label names...
Tip2: It would be a good idea to also insert some array elements that have fewer than 2 digits. If all the array elements have 2 digits, how will you verify that the "number sorting works" ?

From a comment:

> ... is it possible to somehow , take the last digit of array? because I want to compare the eax to last digit of array and je endloop1

Because the *skaic* array holds 5 dwords, the last element (we don't talk about 'digit' in this respect), is located at `skaic + 16`. The offset is 16 because there are 4 elements of each 4 bytes that come before the last element.
In code: `cmp  eax, [skaic + 16]` `je   endT1`.

Alternatively, because the *suma* variable follows the *skaic* array directly in memory, the last element is also found at `suma - 4`.
In code: `cmp  eax, [suma - 4]` `je   endT1`.